# XCode UITests alternative to .StaticText

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

Is there a way to connect to the attribute rather than the static text for a UI element?

When I record a UI test, I get the following

```
sidemenuTable.cells.containingType(.StaticText, identifier:"MULTIMEDIA").childrenMatchingType(.StaticText).matchingIdentifier("MULTIMEDIA").elementBoundByIndex(0).tap()
```

The problem is that the static text changes across targets, and causes the tests to fail. I would like to be able to access an object's properties inside a tableview. E.g. if a custom cell has a property of `cellType`.

This way the tests are indepenent of the text inside the UI elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `textLabel` shortcut on an element's `accessibilityIdentifier`. This isn't presented to the user, so you can make it the same regardless of the element's contents.

Production code:

```
cell.accessibilityIdentifier = "My Cell"
```

Test code:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.staticTexts["My Cell"].tap()
```